# How can I configure Microsoft Teams so that it doesn't disconnect the audio when I receive a phone call during a Teams meeting?

Tags: microsoft-teams

How can I configure Microsoft Teams so that it doesn't disconnect the audio when I receive a phone call during a Teams meeting? I use Android 10 with Samsung Galaxy S9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like this is impossible to  configure Microsoft Teams so that it doesn't disconnect the audio when I receive a phone call during a Teams meeting. From  [barneyman](https://www.reddit.com/user/barneyman) on [Reddit](https://redd.it/oel4ru):

> I don't think you can - Goog's hangouts and meet suffer the same problem